# How to send characters within CodeMirror field using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, codemirror

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, random
import threading

url = 'https://npm.runkit.com/'

def e():

      driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      driver.get(url)
      time.sleep(10)
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/pre/span/span').send_keys('a')


for i in range(1):
    t = threading.Thread(target=e)
    t.start()
```

Image:

[image: The Image]

What I'm trying to do is make the script write in this dialog box where something can be written but i can't select the path always because of this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Could someone do it for me?

Comment: It seems your code is working too. Getting this error is strange

Answer (score 0):

It seems you had copied the wrong path

Please find the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, random
import threading
import os
cwd = os.chdir('C:/Users/huzi95s/Desktop')
url = 'https://npm.runkit.com/'

def e():

     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver.get(url)
     time.sleep(10)
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-container"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div')

for i in range(1):
  t = threading.Thread(target=e)
  t.start()
```

This gives you the dialog box as shown:

[image: dialog]

The trick is to copy XPath and not the full Xpath. This will get rid of the error message

Comment: this still gives the error of (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:) I would like to make the script by typing in the dialog box

Comment: This does not in my browser. See my screenshot. Wait for sometime it will automatically open the browser and load the page for you. After the page is loaded it gives me the same error in my case too.

Comment: the dialog box appears automatically when you wait on the site i would like to make the script recognize it and type the error is strange

Comment: Use explicit waits https://www.techbeamers.com/selenium-webdriver-waits-python/

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within the desired field you need to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get("https://npm.runkit.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://runkit.com/e/iframe')]")))
  time.sleep(10)
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.CodeMirror")))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().send_keys("a").perform()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: CodeMirror]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)